# in org-mode how to auto create new numbering?

Tags: org-mode

I write this in org-mode

- SomeTopic

  1. Anything I can click here to automatically create the below `1.`
  2. Anything I can click here to automatically create the below `1.` automatically indented below?
     1.

For example, I have this line (non header, text):

`1. some item`

I want to click something so it will open `2.` so after I click that something I will have:

```
1. some item
2.
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want. A key combination to indent the second (1.)? The same sub-numbering? Something like org-insert-todo-subheading?

Comment: @Heinrich updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `M-RET` which is bound to `org-meta-return` which in list context calls
`org-insert-item`. E.g.

```
* foo

Let's have a list:

1. itemX
```

where X marks the position of the cursor.
Now press `M-RET`:

```
* foo

Let's have a list:

1. item
2.
```

The [Plain lists](https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html#Plain-lists) section of the manual explains this and many other things that you can do with lists.